# ReactJS/Javascript: Render a list of items to the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two function, `displayElements` and `handleSubmit`.  I am also rendering a date input field to the UI.  What I am trying to do is display the results from the submit button event by calling `displayElements`.

displayElements function:

```
displayElements(){
        var data = this.props.getObjectsQuery;
        console.log(this.props);
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
          if (error) return <p>Error</p>;
          return (
            <Item.Group divided>
              {data.action.map(action =>
                <div>
                  <ul>
                  <li>{action.action}</li>
                  <li>{action.timestamp}</li>
                  <ul>
                  {action.object.map( (obj) => {//the map functions iterates through the array to access each item in the array.
                    return (<li>{obj.filename}</li>)
                  })}
                  </ul>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              )}

              </Item.Group>


            );
        }
      }
    }
```

handleSubmit

```
handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state);
        this.setState({
          startTime: new Date(document.getElementById("startTime").value).valueOf(),//getElementById is a jQuery method
          endTime: new Date(document.getElementById("endTime").value).valueOf()
        }, () => {
          this.props.data.refetch({//Assign the inputvalues, which is the current state, to the variables after pressing the submit button
            startTime: this.state.startTime,
            endTime:this.state.endTime
          });
          console.log(this.state.startTime);
          console.log(this.state.endTime);
        });
      };
```

Render function

render() {

```
console.log(this.props);
return (
  <div className="Calendar">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
      <label>Start Time</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" id="startTime" step="1" />              



      <label>End Time</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" id="endTime" step="1" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       {this.displayElements()}
    </form>

  </div>

);
```

}

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Nothing is showing on the screen. I thoght the displayElements function would take care of that?

Comment: Are you missing an invoke of `displayElements` in your `render` method?

Comment: That's what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to invoke `displayElements` in your `render` method.

The reason you're not seeing anything on the screen is that this function is not invoked anywhere in render.

Comment: Added  {this.displayElements()} and still nothing (see updated code).

Answer (score 0):

Your displayElements return nothing. In your displayElements Function you have another function which is returning your elements. but it didn't actually return to the displayElements function.

```
displayElements() {
// var data = this.props.getObjectsQuery;

const { loading, error, data } = this.state;

if (!!loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
if (!!error) return <p>Error</p>;


return (
    <Item.Group divided>
        {data.action.map(action => (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>{action.action}</li>
                    <li>{action.timestamp}</li>
                    <ul>
                        {action.object.map(obj => {
                            //the map functions iterates through the array to access each item in the array.
                            return <li>{obj.filename}</li>;
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        ))}
    </Item.Group>
    );
}
```

Comment: How do I  invoke displayElements in your render method?

Comment: this.displayElements(). I am here pointing out what you are missing. I don't know the logic here. Example, where does your `loading, error, data` comes from? from the `state`? from the `props`?

Comment: state. Is the placement of this.displayElements() correct in the code? Also, var data is grayed out.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I have destructured what you want from state. Where you invoke your displayElements totally depends on you. If it doesn't belong to the form, it should be called outside of the form.

Comment: @dkulkarni stated above, I need to invoke displayElements in the render method for the elements to show up in the browser.

Comment: @N6DYN, Yes you need to invoke the function. The place you need to invoke is outside of the form in general cases.

Comment: So where I have it in the code above is correct then?

Comment: Nope, it is inside the form tag. here is the sample of what u want. https://codesandbox.io/s/wyq17j7zjk

Comment: No worries, Any link to GitHub or version controls are welcome. I m happy to fix it